# cakePHP4 _ Table class for alias (table_name)users could not be found. error

Tags: cakephp

i continued PHP(CakePHP) study hard
but can not do DB table insert operating.
in this code : TableRegistry::get('users')
'users' is (my_app)database table name.
how can i do make alias 'users'?
and found?
somebody help me please..

```
Table class for alias users could not be found.
Cake\ORM\Exception\MissingTableClassException
CORE\src\ORM\Locator\TableLocator.php
  $message = '`' . $message . '`';
  if (strpos($message, '\\') === false) 
  {
    $message = 'for alias ' . $message;
  }
  throw new MissingTableClassException([$message]);
}
  if (empty($options['connection'])) 
  {
    if (!empty($options['connectionName'])) 
    {
```

```
## templates/User/add.php--------------------------------
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create(NULL,array('url'=>'/users/add'));
    echo $this->Form->control('username');
    echo $this->Form->control('password');
    echo $this->Form->button('Submit');
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
## routers.php-------------------------------------------
// csrf middleware is not problem.
$routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
  $builder->connect('/users/add', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add']);
  $builder->fallbacks();
});
## UsersController.php----------------------------------
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function add()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $username = $this->request->getData('username');
            $hashPswdObj = new DefaultPasswordHasher;
            $password = $hashPswdObj->hash($this->request->getData('password'));
            //TableRegistry :: config ( 'users' , [ 'table' => 'users' ]);
            //$user_table = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users', $config);

            $users_table = TableRegistry::get('users'); //maybe, here is problem

            $users = $users_table->newEntity($this->request->getData());
            $users->username = $username;
            $users->password = $password;
            $this->set('users', $users);
            if($users_table->save($users))
                echo "User is added.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

i reading cakePHP COOKBOOK or site.
but it's impossible

Comment: Do you have a UsersTable class? Is it in the right directory, file and class named correctly, and the right namespace?

Comment: Got the same error, googled this up, double-checked my table class, had a typo in the namespace

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your table have a relation with others. did you create an `user_id` field in your users table? Would you share your table structures?

Below situation will generate error:

> table class for alias (table_name) users could not be found.

let say have table hobbies contain field id, user_id and name;

Then I create HobbiesTable

```
class HobbiesTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('groups');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ]);
    }
```

Definitely I will get error

> table class for alias (table_name) users could not be found

That error is because the hobbies table has belongTo users but the user class is not found. So you must declare usersTable.php too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code top of your `UsersTable.php`:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
   use Cake\ORM\Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add :

namespace App\Model\Table
use Cake\orm\Table;

it works just fyn then

Add the above code in table.php

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).